# Java warn / disallow method in specific package

Tags: java, android, method-invocation

I created a wrapper around [Log.i](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#i(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

```
public class MyLog {
  public static int i(String tag, String message) {
    //Do Stuff
    return Log.i(tag, message);
  }
}
```

Now I'd like all my consumers `com.myapp.package1`, `com.myapp.package2`, etc. to use `MyLog.i` instead of `Log.i`.  Currently, we're just enforcing this by conventions and documentation.  Are there more aggressive programatic ways to discourage or disable developers from calling `Log.i` from within certain packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not within the language itself.  THis is something better done by either your build system or your source control system.  A lint rule would work, with your build system set to error out or your source control set to reject diffs that fail the rule.